# adding objects into an existing object

Tags: javascript, json, object, d3.js

I need to load an external JSON file using a d3.json function which for eg. has this format

```
{"pole":[{"name": "p1"}, {"name":"p2"}]}
```

In the main file, I would have

```
var MainData ={}; d3.json("url", function(graph){MainData[graph] = graph;});
```

gives me the external JSON object pushed inside MainData. But I would lie to be able to access it as MainData.pole

Also I would like to load multiple JSON files and push them into the same MainData file.

I am new to JS and I would very much appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var MainData ={}; d3.json("url", function(graph){MainData[graph] = graph;});
> ```
>
> gives me the external JSON object pushed inside MainData.

Well, sort of, but it's got a *really* awkward property name, most likely `[object Object]`, because when you use brackets notation like that, the property name within the brackets is given as a *string* (for now; ES6 adds `Symbol`s), so any non-string you put there will be turned into a string. The default result of calling `toString` on a plain object is `[object Object]`.

> But I would lie to be able to access it as `MainData.pole`

Assuming `d3.json` parses it for you before giving it to you, then:

```
var MainData ={};
d3.json("url", function(graph) { 
    MainData.pole = graph.pole;
});
```

If you're expected to parse it yourself (which seems unlikely), then:

```
var MainData ={};
d3.json("url", function(graph) { 
    MainData.pole = JSON.parse(graph).pole;
});
```